# Terragrunt out to environment variable GitLab CI/CD

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, terragrunt

I'm trying to run a "Terragrunt plan -out=$PLAN" but it seems I'm unable to? My goal here is to output a plan then show the plan and post to a GitLab merge request.

How should I go about accomplishing this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    - terragrunt plan -out $PLAN
    - "terragrunt show --json $PLAN | convert_report > $JSON_PLAN_FILE"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $PLAN
    reports:
      terraform: $JSON_PLAN_FILE
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to just create files instead of piping out to a variable and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same issue and decided to update this thread with my findings, as its one of the only ones that came up when I performed a very-specific google search for my problem (displaying terraform plan reports in merge requests when running **terragrunt** in a monorepo).

Here's the line in my `gitlab-ci.yml` that performs the plan (actually multiple plans in various submodules):

```
terragrunt run-all show --json $PLAN 2>/dev/null | convert_report >> $JSON_PLAN_FILE
```

**Notes**:

- I copied `convert_report` straight from Gitlab's [terraform report artifacts docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/mr_integration.html#configure-terraform-report-artifacts)
- `2>/dev/null` was necessary to get rid of all the `terragrunt` output (and only display the `terraform` json output that feeds into `jq`

Then I had to do some massaging in python to format it into the output Gitlab expects:

```
{
  "create": 0,
  "update": 0,
  "delete": 0
}
```

The python massaging is also required to combine these values and separate them into logical chunks (arbitrary, based on what I want to group by) so that they can be presented as [separate resources in merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/mr_integration.html#multiple-terraform-plan-reports)

Hope that helps the next weary internet traveler that stumbles upon this post save some time :)